# rails sending email that has a href link in a button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

Im sending a confirmation email (that works now yay!), In the email I want the link to show up as a button.

I tried this:

```
<p><%= link_to t('.action', default: 'Confirm my account'),
         confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token, locale: I18n.locale), class: "btn btn-primary" %></p>
```

where I append the , class: "btn btn-primary", but it didn't work.
Whats the correct way to do this?

I have bootstrap install and working in my app. I've heard you need to reference bootstrap in your email, but how?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
</head>
<body> 

<p><%= link_to t('.action', default: 'Confirm my account'), confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token, locale: I18n.locale), class: "btn btn-primary" %></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you referencing `bootstrap.css` in the mailer layout?

Comment: probably not im a beginner, how do I check and/or reference bootstrap.css?

Comment: i have bootstrap set up and running in my app, but not referenced in my mailer if that's what your asking

Comment: You're gonna need it there so the `btn` style works.

Comment: YES! but how do i do that

Comment: How would you set up this to ref bootstrap

Comment: Could you please add this to the question itself, it's really hard to read this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure,why **bootstrap** is not working as you it works by adding `btn` class to a tag.However,without relying on existing styles,If you want to show a link as a button in the email,you can simply use css.Try to add this class.Also remove the `p` tag.

```
     ####css    
    .button {
      background-color: red;  
      border-radius: 5px;
      color: white;
      padding: .5em;
      text-decoration: none;
      display:block;
    }
    .button:focus,
    .button:hover {
      background-color: DarkGreen;
    }


####html
<%= link_to t('.action', default: 'Confirm my account'),
         confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token, locale: I18n.locale), class: "button" %>
```

More examples are [here](https://designshack.net/articles/css/css-button-tutorial-how-to-code-buttons-in-5-simple-steps/)

Comment: So how would you write in the css , make everything like a normal html text ? is that what your saying

Comment: Yes..i added style tag inside my email template.